# Taking the difference between matrices of different dimensions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `m x 3`, e.g. `m=18`

```
A=[ 2| 1 1;
    3| 1 2;
   -8| 1 3;
   -------
   -5| 1 1;
    2| 1 2;
    6| 1 3;
   -------
    7| 2 1;
    3| 2 2;
    1| 2 3;
    5| 2 4;
   -------
    3| 2 1;
   -8| 2 2;
    1| 2 3;
    0| 2 4;
   -------
    1| 2 1;
    2| 2 2;
    7| 2 3;
    9| 2 4]
```

The characteristics of `A` are the following:

1. It is composed by `t` submatrices. In the example `t=5`.
2. Each submatrix `t` has dimension `b x 3` with `b<=m` and `b` can take any value in `{3,4,5,...,m}` (clearly, in a way such that the sum of all rows is `m`). In the example, the first and the second submatrices have dimension `3 x 3`, the last three submatrices have dimension `4 x 3`.
3. All submatrices of the same dimension are stacked one after the other. In the example, firstly we have the submatrices `3 x 3` and then the submatrices `4 x 3`.

Then I have a matrix `B` of dimension `f x 3` where `f=size(unique(A(:,2:end),'rows','stable'),1)` where the last two columns reproduce the elements in `unique(A(:,2:end),'rows','stable')`, e.g. in the eample above `f=7` and

```
B=[2| 1 1;
   3| 1 2;
   1| 1 3;
   7| 2 1;
   8| 2 2;
  10| 2 3;
   2| 2 4]
```

I want to construct (possible without loops) a matrix  `C` of dimension `f x t` such that `C(:,i)` is computed by

1) take the `i`-th sub-matrix of `A` and call it `H`. The number of rows of `H` is `<f`. The number of columns of `H` is `3`. E.g. if `i=1` in the example,

```
H=[2| 1 1;
   3| 1 2;
  -8| 1 3]
```

2) compute `D=ismember(B(:,2:3),H(:,2:3),'rows')` of dimension `f x 1`. When `i=1` in the example, `D=[1 1 1 0 0 0 0]'`;

3) Generate `E(f,1)=0`, i.e. in the example `E=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]'`.

4) Replace `E(D)=H(:,i)`, i.e. in the example with `i=1`, `E=[2 3 -8 0 0 0 0]`

5) Compute `C(:,i)=E-B(:,1)`, i.e. in the example with `i=1`,

```
C(:,1)=[2-2;
        3-3;
       -8-1; 
        0-7;
        0-8;
        0-10;
        0-2]
```

In the example above summarising for all `i`

```
C=[ 2-2 | -5-2 | 0-2 | 0-2 | 0-2 ;
    3-3 |  2-3 | 0-3 | 0-3 | 0-3 ;
   -8-1 |  6-1 | 0-1 | 0-1 | 0-1 ;
    0-7 |  0-7 | 7-7 | 3-7 | 1-7 ;
    0-8 |  0-8 | 3-8 |-8-8 | 2-8 ;
   0-10 | 0-10 |1-10 |1-10 | 7-10;
    0-2 |  0-2 | 5-2 | 0-2 | 9-2;]
```

I have a rough idea on how to construct `C` using a loop; I would appreciate any suggestion that does not require looping and is possibly fast given that the actual matrices I'm working with have huge dimensions. One idea (that I don't know how to implement) could be: creating a cell variable of dimension `tx1` in which in each cell I put a sub-matrix of `A`, then applying steps 2),3),4),5) to each cell and re-assembling.

Comment: I get lost while reading your computation steps.  Would it be possible to show what the resulting calculations are at each step you're describing?  It goes a longer way if you can pictorially show what each step does.

Comment: I can't see how this can be done without loops.  Each submatrix may potentially be a different size, so it would be difficult to get this done vectorized.

Comment: Could you suggest the most efficient loop that you have in mind for doing this?

Comment: @rayryeng One idea (that I don't know how to implement) could be: creating a cell variable of dimension tx1 in which in each cell I put a sub-matrix of A, then applying steps 2),3),4),5) to each cell and re-assembling. What do you think?

Comment: That sounds very suitable... but that will require a loop over each submatrix.  Is that what you want?

Comment: ok, a loop seems unavoidable in this case, thank you. Or maybe we could use cellfun to apply the same function to each cell.

Comment: Yes we can certainly do that.  I'll think about it and get back to you.  BTW, have you tried anything on your end?  Do you have something working, or are you also stuck?

Comment: Working on it. I'll share if I get something! Thank you

Comment: Sounds good!  Let me think about the most efficient way to do this and I'll post an answer.  My gut says we have to do this with a loop... but I will try without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I hope I got what you wanted, as your example and code were not easy to follow. Regarding loops you just need one, and as one level loop is compiled it shouldn't be a problem.

First your input data, I transposed just for readability, and I added an index column that corresponds to your lines.

```
 A = [1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5
      2   3  -8  -5   2   6   7   3   1   5   3  -8   1   0   1   2   7   9
      1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
      1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4]';

 B = [2  3  1  7  8 10  2
      1  1  1  2  2  2  2
      1  2  3  1  2  3  4]';

t = length(unique(A(:,1)));
C = zeros(f,t);

for ii=1:length(unique(A(:,1)))
  C(ismember(B(:,2:3),A(A(:,1)==ii,3:4),'rows'),ii) = A(A(:,1)==ii,2);
  C(:,ii) = C(:,ii)-B(:,1);
end
```

The output will be what you wanted

```
 C = [0    -7    -2    -2    -2
      0    -1    -3    -3    -3
     -9     5    -1    -1    -1
     -7    -7     0    -4    -6
     -8    -8    -5   -16    -6
    -10   -10    -9    -9    -3
     -2    -2     3    -2     7];
```

enjoy